# Readying 1 large csv file in chunk with Spark structured streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I have 1 large CSV file. I would like to know if it possible to read and process 1 csv file in chunks with Spark structured streaming, and if yes how to control the size of those chunks (i.e. which config to use to control it).

Said differently, can i configure things such that to process 100 rows per micro-batch. If not the number of row then the number of bite.

In a sense i would like to read process write at the same time in micro batches.